# Jitsi -Signal ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed

Tags: android, react-native, signals, messenger, jitsi

I Tried to combine Jitsi Android SDK and signal messenger, the jitsi run well until another participant joined room, and jitsi SDK crash return the following error in logcat :

`Channel 'c06d484 xxx org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! Camera3-OutputStream: returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32) E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32 [TransactFailed]`

i used the proguard-rules.pro but still didnt works.

I Found The Problem, The WebRTC library in ringtc_rffi.so (ringRTC Library signal) is conflict with libjingle_peerConection.so,

Any body know how to separate system to read the libjingle_peerConection or ringtc_rffi?

Comment: HI did you manage to solve this issue?